# appstore update refusal with strange resolution

Tags: app-store, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller, app-store-connect

I submitted my new version of my application but it be refused and the resolution said

```
10.3: Apps that do not use system provided items, such as buttons and icons, correctly and as described in the Apple iPhone Human Interface Guidelines and the Apple iPad Human Interface Guidelines may be rejected
We found your app uses system-provided items in a non-standard manner, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Please refer to the attached screenshot for more information.

As recommended by the iOS Human Interface Guidelines, Pickers should only be presented within a popover element and should not take up the entire width of the screen.

Learn more about system-provided items in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines, sections: "System-Provided Buttons and Icons" and "iOS UI Element Usage Guidelines."
```

[image]
the problem is that this part didn't be modified in this version and be accepted several time before

does the standard change or what, if yes how to correct that

Comment: I think you should consider phoning Apple Developer Support and tell them this - or use the resolution center within iTunes Connect online to argue your case. If they don't change their stance then I'm afraid you will have to make the required changes. Best of luck, keep us posted! https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that you should be using the picker view in a popover and not take up the width of the screen.

Just because your app did this previously in earlier versions and was accepted, doesn't mean that they can't reject it in later versions. Particularly as it is explicitly stated in the guidelines that a pop over should be used in these cases.

Comment: and remain it taking the width in iphone

Comment: I also the whole width in iphone case but the snapshot come regardign the ipad

Comment: The HIG section for the picker control clearly states that on iPad, the picker **must** be presented in a popover. There is no such restriction for iPhone.